# How to cast an object in class loaded in classloader

Tags: groovy, casting, groovyclassloader

I am new to Stack Overflow. I have created a Groovy class loader's object in which I have loaded all the classes required by my script. I have task of serializing and deserializing an object created of one of the class that is loaded in class loader. Problem is while deserializing I am not able to cast the object in the class as class in loaded in class loader. I don't know how to cast an object in a class that is loaded in a class loader. Can some one help me in this. The ????? in below snippet is a class that is loaded in class loader but how shall I achieve this.

```
Object o = null
new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes).withObjectInputStream(getClass().classLoader){ gin ->
                                o = (?????)gin.readObject() }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How does your code look like now? Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, your answer was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve your problem. Let me show you a working example

Some `Employee` class, that I use

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable
{
    public String name;
    public String address;
}
```

Then the `Main` class

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee()
        e1.name = 'John'
        e1.address = 'Main Street'

        byte[] bytes = []

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(stream)
        out.writeObject(e1)
        bytes = stream.toByteArray()
        out.close()
        stream.close()

        Object o = null
        new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes).withObjectInputStream(Main.getClassLoader()){ gin ->
            o = gin.readObject()
        }

        print o instanceof Employee
        println 'Deserialized Employee...'
        println 'Name: ' + o.name
        println 'Address: ' + o.address
    }
}
```

Instead of doing `getClass().classLoader`, which was throwing a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, I am doing `Main.getClassLoader()`. This classloader is able to find my `Employee` class.

Moreover, you don't really need to cast the object, it is groovy, its dynamic, so you get the `name` and `address` fields at runtime.

But, you can always check the type of the object and then cast it:

```
print o instanceof Employee
```

this will return `true`